# Perm Error sometimes not know if it sender issue or receiver issue

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

I am facing the problem, sometimes from the sender , i am able to receive the mail, sometimes it block, getting the error ---

```
Sender: @dekra.com
Recipient: @autodienst-hoppegarten.de
```

working header: when its working fine

```
Received: from inbound-52-29-100-147-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com ([52.29.100.147]:35227)
    by out.mb-recker.de with esmtps  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    (Exim 4.96)
    (envelope-from <YYYY@dekra.com>)
    id 1r1SkG-0004sd-1M
    for XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de;
    Fri, 10 Nov 2023 15:44:28 +0100
Received: from ip-172-20-100-54.eu-4444-1.compute.internal (ip-172-20-100-54.eu-4444-1.compute.internal [127.0.0.1])
    by inbound-52-29-100-147-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4SRhRc05NKzsR5j
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Fri, 10 Nov 2023 14:44:28 +0000 (UTC)
Authentication-Results: mx-01-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=YYYY@dekra.com; dkim=none; dmarc=pass (recordpolicy=none) header.from=dekra.com
Received-SPF: PermError (EXRG01.rg.loc: domain of YYYY@dekra.com
used an invalid SPF mechanism)
Received-SPF: pass receiver=mx-01-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com; client-ip=91.205.36.214; envelope-from=<YYYY@dekra.com>; helo=mailout.dekra.com;
X-zzzz-Product-Type: Gateway
X-zzzz-Email-ID: a016f084d43444758f803e4a49ef396f
Received: from mailout.dekra.com (mailout.dekra.com [91.205.36.214])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mx-01-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 4SRhRQ4j5dzdZMF
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Fri, 10 Nov 2023 14:44:18 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from palogsrv.edv.dekra.de (uapap04-ch1.edv.dekra.de [10.112.216.214])
    by mailout.dekra.com (AIX7.2/8.15.2/8.14.4) with ESMTP id 3AAEiHEx21692878
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Fri, 10 Nov 2023 15:44:17 +0100
Received: from uapap04 (loopback [127.0.0.1])
    by palogsrv.edv.dekra.de (AIX7.1/8.14.4/8.11.0) with ESMTP id 3AAEiHbr40370402
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Fri, 10 Nov 2023 15:44:17 +0100
```

Non working

```
Received: from inbound-52-58-166-242-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com ([52.58.166.242]:65164)
    by out.mb-recker.de with esmtps  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    (Exim 4.96)
    (envelope-from <YYYY@dekra.com>)
    id 1r1PZf-0000e5-1Q
    for XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de;
    Fri, 10 Nov 2023 12:21:19 +0100
Received: from ip-172-20-101-192.eu-4444-1.compute.internal (ip-172-20-101-192.eu-4444-1.compute.internal [127.0.0.1])
    by inbound-52-58-166-242-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4SRbxC169rzHnJS
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Fri, 10 Nov 2023 11:21:19 +0000 (UTC)
Authentication-Results: mx-01-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com; spf=permerror smtp.mailfrom=YYYY@dekra.com; dkim=none; dmarc=fail (recordpolicy=none) header.from=dekra.com
Received-SPF: PermError (EXRG01.rg.loc: domain of YYYY@dekra.com
used an invalid SPF mechanism)
Received-SPF: permerror receiver=mx-01-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com; client-ip=91.205.36.214; envelope-from=<YYYY@dekra.com>; helo=mailout.dekra.com;
X-zzzz-Product-Type: Gateway
X-zzzz-Email-ID: 3d0fd0853f1540899c2adfba97e538ea
Received: from mailout.dekra.com (mailout.dekra.com [91.205.36.214])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mx-01-eu-4444-1.prod.hydra.zzzz.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 4SR3jF5l8NzbbZ7
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Thu,  9 Nov 2023 14:09:05 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from palogsrv.edv.dekra.de (uapap04-ch1.edv.dekra.de [10.112.216.214])
    by mailout.dekra.com (AIX7.2/8.15.2/8.14.4) with ESMTP id 3A9E95aT13107678
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Thu, 9 Nov 2023 15:09:05 +0100
Received: from uapap04 (loopback [127.0.0.1])
    by palogsrv.edv.dekra.de (AIX7.1/8.14.4/8.11.0) with ESMTP id 3A9E946X16056336
    for <XXXX@autodienst-hoppegarten.de>; Thu, 9 Nov 2023 15:09:04 +0100
Date: Thu, 9 Nov 2023 15:09:04 +0100
```

Comment: Maybe if `@dekra.com` was slightly more specific about their authorized senders than "one of these 100000 v4 addresses, probably" you might want to care.. I do not have proof, but it does not seem too unlikely that they also briefly exceeded the lookup limit, leading your end to note down `permerror`.

Comment: @anx,thanking you for the answer,